# Linear Regression Model missing an argument .fit

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write a linear regression model but I get a type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-65-8a233a281e65> in <module>()
      2 y_val= df['GOOGL']
      3 body_reg =linear_model.LinearRegression
----> 4 body_reg.fit(x_val, y_val)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

This is the code I have so after importing sklearn, pandas, etc.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\GOOGTICKER.CSV')
df
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
grouped= df.groupby([times.year]).mean()
from sklearn import linear_model
x_val= df['MSFT']
y_val= df['GOOGL']
body_reg =linear_model.LinearRegression
body_reg.fit(x_val, y_val)
```

Am I missing an argument?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the class:

```
body_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

Comment: I get an error saying: C:\Users\Brian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:395: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)

Comment: Also ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 2246]